# Did the 1500 hour rule expire?

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations

So the 1500 hour legislation was set to expire on the 30th of September 2015. Anyone know the outcome of the expiration. Did congress extend the rule, or is it no longer in effect. I tried searching the web but couldn't find any info.

Comment: Do you have a link or citation? I'm not sure that's the correct interpretation of the situation.

Comment: This is where I saw the 9/30 date listed http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/2015/08/27/pilot-shortage-faa-1500-hours-required-colgan-crash-alpa/32008451/

Comment: What is the 1500 hours rule? Is it country specific?

Answer (score 3):

**The 1500 hour rule is still in effect.**

The rule wasn't set to expire on the 30th of September; **technically *the entire FAA was going to expire*.** Congress [votes on the authorization for the FAA to regulate air transportation](http://www.aopa.org/News-and-Video/All-News/2015/July/01/FAA-reauthorization-bill-delayed); that authorization was set to expire 30 September, 2015.

[The House voted to authorize funding on 28 September](http://www.aopa.org/News-and-Video/All-News/2015/September/28/House-passes-FAA-funding-extension) while the Senate [passed a 6-month extension on 29 September](http://www.postbulletin.com/news/politics/congress-votes-to-renew-faa-authority-for-months/article_0ddbf55a-c615-56ad-bb2d-b2c7453ebff1.html).

Expect to see similar discussions in 6 months.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @egid : "technically the entire FAA was going to expire" ?  Who would take over regulating air transportation?

Comment: @user6035379 no one. In the US, An agency being authorized to exist and perform their functions lasts only as long as their funding does. Laws funding agencies are typically only for a small number of years at a time. If the law expires the agency shuts down. Sometimes this happens to the whole government and it is a mess.

Comment: @BSteinhurst : I don't understand.  No funding for the FAA.  Then what happens to aviation?  People stop flying?

Comment: @user6035379 traffic control are probably one of the essential services that keep going so flying is ok. But the regulators, the folks who make the rules and generally anyone who works in an office would be prevented from working. That is why not passing budgets until the last minute is a great American pastime.